# Printing tensor sometimes returns shape of the tensor in Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

So I have this tensor called bids, and I try to filter some values of it for debugging purposes. However, some filters do return the filtered tensor, and some return the shape of the tensor as shown below:

```
bids[bids>=0]
> tensor([0.6249, 0.2195, 0.1606,  ..., 0.1114, 0.2826, 0.8744],
       grad_fn=<IndexBackward>)
bids[bids<0]
> tensor([], grad_fn=<IndexBackward>)

bids[bids=='nan']
>tensor([], size=(0, 1024, 2, 1), grad_fn=<IndexBackward>)
```

Does anybody have any idea why this happens? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

That's because the result from the masking operation is empty (notice how one of the dimensions is equal to zero). The reason is you have no elements in `bids` that equal `'nan'`. In turn, this makes the mask `bids == 'nan'` comprised of only zero values.

Here is a minimal example:

```
>>> bids = torch.arange(10)
>>> bids[bids=='nan']
tensor([], size=(0, 10), dtype=torch.int64)
```

Comment: makes sense, however, when I execute bids[bids<0], the result is again an empty tensor, but the size is then not returned. Why do you think that this happens?

Comment: I would assume it's because the `'nan'` value can never be a tensor value since it's a string...